# Как получить элемент ListView при нажатии кнопки в Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

В каждом элементе ListView внутри ViewCell вставлена кнопка для удаления этого элемента из списка и соответственно из ListView. Как в обработчике события нажатия на кнопку BDeleteIngredient_Clicked получить ссылку на элемент или номер элемента ListView в котором нажата эта кнопка?

```
    <ListView x:Name="lvIngredients" Margin="20" ItemSelected="LvIngredients_ItemSelected">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                        <Button Image="ic_action_trash.png" Clicked="BDeleteIngredient_Clicked"
                               WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="40" CornerRadius="20" BackgroundColor="DodgerBlue" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

private void BDeleteIngredient_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

sender.Parent возвращает объект StackLayout, sender.Parent.Parent возвращает объект ViewCell, а sender.Parent.Parent.Parent возвращает объект ListView. А как получить соотвествующий Item из ListView?

Answer (score 1):

В общем все оказалось просто:

```
private void BDeleteIngredient_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    ViewCell viewCell = button.Parent.Parent as ViewCell;
    Ingredient ingredient = (Ingredient)viewCell.BindingContext;
}
```

Получаем непосредственно элемент коллекции, привязанный к нужному Item ListView, а дальше просто находим этот Item или работаем непосредственно с элементом коллекции.